# Construct a performant sieve of Atkin in Rust

Tags: performance, rust, primes, memory-optimization

I have implemented the sieve of Atkin in Rust. It can find all primes till 1,000,000,000 in 4.5 s using 34.4 MiB on my 1.4 GHz machine. This is a direct implementation (with some optimisations made from empirical observations) of [Atkin and Bernstein's paper](http://www.ams.org/mcom/2004-73-246/S0025-5718-03-01501-1/S0025-5718-03-01501-1.pdf). Here, `sieve` is `Vec<u16>` in which the `i`th element indicates whether the 16 numbers `60 * i + d` are prime, where `d` is a coprime residue modulo 60. Further, `isqrt` is the integer square root function (implementation not shown here) which I had to use because [integer square roots are not stabilised in Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i64.html#method.isqrt).

```rust
/// A. O. L. Atkin and D. J. Bernstein, "Prime Sieves Using Binary Quadratic
/// Forms", in Mathematics of Computation, vol. 73, no. 246, pp. 1023–1030.
pub struct SieveOfAtkin {
    limit: usize,
    limit_rounded: usize,
    limit_rounded_root: usize,
    sieve: Vec<u16>,
}
impl SieveOfAtkin {
    // Consecutive differences between coprime residues modulo 60: 1, 7, 11,
    // 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 49, 53 and 59.
    const OFFSETS: [usize; 16] = [6, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2, 6, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2];
    // Position of the bit indicating the primality of a coprime residue modulo
    // 60 in a 16-element bitfield. For non-coprime residues, the value is 16.
    const SHIFTS: [u8; 60] = [
        16, 0, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 1, 16, 16, 16, 2, 16, 3, 16, 16, 16, 4, 16, 5, 16, 16, 16, 6,
        16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 7, 16, 8, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 9, 16, 16, 16, 10, 16, 11, 16, 16, 16,
        12, 16, 13, 16, 16, 16, 14, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 15,
    ];
}
impl SieveOfAtkin {
    /// Construct the sieve of Atkin up to and including the given number.
    ///
    /// * `limit` - Non-strict upper bound.
    ///
    /// -> Sieve of Atkin.
    pub fn new(limit: usize) -> SieveOfAtkin {
        // Strict upper bound divisible by 60.
        let limit_rounded = (limit - limit % 60)
            .checked_add(60)
            .expect("overflow detected; argument too large");
        let mut sieve_of_atkin = SieveOfAtkin {
            limit,
            limit_rounded,
            limit_rounded_root: isqrt(limit_rounded as i64) as usize,
            sieve: vec![0; limit / 60 + 1],
        };
        sieve_of_atkin.init();
        sieve_of_atkin
    }
    fn init(&mut self) {
        // Note: it runs faster like this than with loops.
        self.algorithm_3_1(1);
        self.algorithm_3_1(13);
        self.algorithm_3_1(17);
        self.algorithm_3_1(29);
        self.algorithm_3_1(37);
        self.algorithm_3_1(41);
        self.algorithm_3_1(49);
        self.algorithm_3_1(53);
        self.algorithm_3_2(7);
        self.algorithm_3_2(19);
        self.algorithm_3_2(31);
        self.algorithm_3_2(43);
        self.algorithm_3_3(11);
        self.algorithm_3_3(23);
        self.algorithm_3_3(47);
        self.algorithm_3_3(59);

        // Mark composite all numbers divisible by the squares of primes.
        let mut num: usize = 1;
        let mut offset = SieveOfAtkin::OFFSETS.iter().cycle();
        'sieve: for sieve_idx in 0..self.sieve.len() {
            for shift in 0..16 {
                if self.sieve[sieve_idx] >> shift & 1 == 1 {
                    let num_sqr = num.pow(2);
                    for multiple in (num_sqr..)
                        .step_by(num_sqr)
                        .take_while(|&multiple| multiple < self.limit_rounded)
                    {
                        let multiple_div_60 = multiple / 60;
                        let multiple_mod_60 = multiple % 60;
                        self.sieve[multiple_div_60] &=
                            !(1u32 << SieveOfAtkin::SHIFTS[multiple_mod_60]) as u16;
                    }
                }
                num += offset.next().unwrap();
                if num > self.limit_rounded_root {
                    break 'sieve;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fn algorithm_3_1(&mut self, delta: i32) {
        for f in 1..=15 {
            for g in (1..=30).step_by(2) {
                let quadratic = 4 * f * f + g * g;
                if delta == quadratic % 60 {
                    self.algorithm_4_1(delta, f, g, quadratic / 60);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fn algorithm_3_2(&mut self, delta: i32) {
        for f in (1..=10).step_by(2) {
            for g in [2, 4, 8, 10, 14, 16, 20, 22, 26, 28] {
                let quadratic = 3 * f * f + g * g;
                if delta == quadratic % 60 {
                    self.algorithm_4_2(delta, f, g, quadratic / 60);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fn algorithm_3_3(&mut self, delta: i32) {
        for (f, gstart) in (1..=10).zip([2, 1].into_iter().cycle()) {
            for g in (gstart..=30).step_by(2) {
                let quadratic = 3i32 * f * f - g * g;
                // Remainder can be negative, so perform modulo operation.
                if delta == quadratic.rem_euclid(60) {
                    self.algorithm_4_3(delta, f, g, quadratic.div_euclid(60));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fn algorithm_4_1(&mut self, delta: i32, f: i32, g: i32, h: i32) {
        let (mut x, mut y0, mut k0) = (f as i64, g as i64, h as i64);
        while k0 < self.sieve.len() as i64 {
            (k0, x) = (k0 + 2 * x + 15, x + 15);
        }
        loop {
            (k0, x) = (k0 - 2 * x + 15, x - 15);
            if x <= 0 {
                return;
            }
            while k0 < 0 {
                (k0, y0) = (k0 + y0 + 15, y0 + 30);
            }
            let (mut k, mut y) = (k0, y0);
            while k < self.sieve.len() as i64 {
                self.sieve[k as usize] ^= 1u16 << SieveOfAtkin::SHIFTS[delta as usize];
                (k, y) = (k + y + 15, y + 30);
            }
        }
    }
    fn algorithm_4_2(&mut self, delta: i32, f: i32, g: i32, h: i32) {
        let (mut x, mut y0, mut k0) = (f as i64, g as i64, h as i64);
        while k0 < self.sieve.len() as i64 {
            (k0, x) = (k0 + x + 5, x + 10);
        }
        loop {
            (k0, x) = (k0 - x + 5, x - 10);
            if x <= 0 {
                return;
            }
            while k0 < 0 {
                (k0, y0) = (k0 + y0 + 15, y0 + 30);
            }
            let (mut k, mut y) = (k0, y0);
            while k < self.sieve.len() as i64 {
                self.sieve[k as usize] ^= 1u16 << SieveOfAtkin::SHIFTS[delta as usize];
                (k, y) = (k + y + 15, y + 30);
            }
        }
    }
    fn algorithm_4_3(&mut self, delta: i32, f: i32, g: i32, h: i32) {
        let (mut x, mut y0, mut k0) = (f as i64, g as i64, h as i64);
        loop {
            while k0 >= self.sieve.len() as i64 {
                if x <= y0 {
                    return;
                }
                (k0, y0) = (k0 - y0 - 15, y0 + 30);
            }
            let (mut k, mut y) = (k0, y0);
            while k >= 0 && y < x {
                self.sieve[k as usize] ^= 1u16 << SieveOfAtkin::SHIFTS[delta as usize];
                (k, y) = (k - y - 15, y + 30);
            }
            (k0, x) = (k0 + x + 5, x + 10);
        }
    }
    pub fn is_prime(&self, num: usize) -> bool {
        if num < 2 {
            return false;
        }
        if num == 2 || num == 3 || num == 5 {
            return true;
        }
        let num_div_60 = num / 60;
        let num_mod_60 = num % 60;
        if num_div_60 >= self.sieve.len() {
            panic!("queried number is out of range of the sieve")
        }
        self.sieve[num_div_60] & (1u32 << SieveOfAtkin::SHIFTS[num_mod_60]) as u16 != 0
    }
    pub fn iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = i64> + '_ {
        let mut num: usize = 1;
        let mut offset = SieveOfAtkin::OFFSETS.iter().cycle();
        [2, 3, 5]
            .into_iter()
            .chain(
                self.sieve
                    .iter()
                    .flat_map(|bitfield| (0..16).map(move |shift| bitfield >> shift & 1 == 1))
                    .filter_map(move |is_prime| {
                        let filtered = if is_prime { Some(num) } else { None };
                        num += offset.next().unwrap();
                        filtered
                    }),
            )
            .take_while(|&num| num <= self.limit)
            .map(|num| num as i64)
    }
}
```

[Bernstein's implementation](http://cr.yp.to/primegen.html) runs in 3.0 s, but it has a ton of optimisations in the form of lookups instead of branches and calculations in a number of places, so I am not looking to emulate the same. Nonetheless, [`cargo-flamegraph`](https://github.com/flamegraph-rs/flamegraph) tells me that this code spends most of the time running algorithms 4.1, 4.2 and 4.3, and the `iter` method.

- Are there any (possibly mathematical) optimisations I can make to further improve the performance?
- I realise that algorithms 3.1, 3.2 and 3.3 are similar (as are algorithms 4.1 and 4.2). Could some parts be factored out without blowing up the argument list? (Not at the cost of performance, though, since these are small functions.)
- Documentation is clearly lacking; however, being that this is an implementation of a paper which explains everything in detail, what comments can I add without duplicating the paper (and things like bit-clear or bit-set, which I think are common knowledge)?
- Is there a better (and faster) way to write the `iter` method?

Comment: You could factor out the constants in the otherwise equivalent algorithms as generic constants of the functions and then invoke them using those. Also the names are not really descriptive. By just reading `algorithm_4_3` I'd have no idea what it does.

Comment: @RichardNeumann Noted—I had considered, for instance, `gen_triplets_for_delta_11_mod_12` and similar alternatives instead of `algorithm_4_3`, but felt that would detract from the concise descriptions laid out in the paper.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you for the citation.

The comments describing OFFSETS and SHIFTS are illuminating
and I thank you for them. But I'm a little sad to see the
math relationships written in English rather than as a
trivial algorithm. If we stored the cited [1, 7, ..., 53, 59],
then helpers could come up with the offset and shift values.

## compiler optimization

```
        // Note: it runs faster like this than with loops.
```

This is a fascinating remark,
which leaves the reader curious about what intra-function
optimizations the compiler was able to see in the "constant" case,
and what it would take to enable similar behavior in the "variable" case.

Sorry, you lost me with these temp vars:

```
                let multiple_div_60 = multiple / 60;
                let multiple_mod_60 = multiple % 60;
                self.sieve[multiple_div_60] &=
                    !(1u32 << SieveOfAtkin::SHIFTS[multiple_mod_60]) as u16;
```

It's unclear why those two expressions were worth naming.
Maybe it was just a debugging thing, during development?
Or maybe they're leftover from an attempt to make "addition and conditional"
go faster than integer division?
That's something that could possibly help `.iter()`,
given its sequential scan.
Or maybe start a bunch of threads, each focused on just a single mod 60 offset?

In any event, thank you for the nicely named `limit_rounded`
and `limit_rounded_root` identifiers, they are very clear.
Similarly, I like the traceability that the `algorithm_X_Y` names give us.
The source is inseparable from the paper; they must be read together.
I feel the source has the appropriate amount of documentation and comments.

There are some md5 hashes at the end of the paper,
which an accompanying rust test suite could go to the trouble of verifying.

Comment: I was unable to figure out a way to construct `OFFSETS` from `[1, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 49, 53, 59]`. Looks like Rust doesn't permit all kinds of computations in constants.

Comment: The temporary variables were indeed for debugging! As for tests, I have added three to verify that it correctly finds the number of primes till `2.pow(14)` (1,900), `10.pow(9)` (50,847,534) and `2.pow(36)` (2,874,398,515). They don't actually check each number, though, so that's one possible area of improvement. Thanks for the multithreading suggestion! I'll see what I can do.